Windows 10で Android Virtual Device（AVD）を作成したいのですが、intel/haxm のインストールするに失敗します
Windows10でデバイス マネージャを使用して Android Virtual Device（AVD）を作成したいのですが、intel/haxmをインストールするように促されるのでインストールしようとするも、失敗します。
エラーログ
C:\xxxx\Temp\haxm_install-20241006_xxxx.log
Version: 7.6.5
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM
Extract: checktool.exe... 100%
Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       *  Yes
VMX enabled         -  No
EPT supported       *  Yes
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.19045
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
The system requirements are not satisfied.

試したこと

AIに聞いたら「VMX enabled - No」が原因なので、BIOS設定の変更を促されたのですが、BIOSにはそれらしき設定項目が見当たりません。
AIに聞いたら「Windowsの機能」ウィンドウが開いたら、リストの中から「Hyper-V」を見つけてチェックを外します。と回答されたのですが、「Hyper-V」の項目が見つかりません
Windows Hypervisor Platformにはすでにチェックを入っていて有効になっていました。

下記(AI回答)を試しましたが、効果ありませんでした

コマンドプロンプトを管理者権限で開き、以下のコマンドを実行して Hyper-V を無効にしてみてください。
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
その後、PC を再起動して再度 HAXM をインストールしてみてください。

環境
・Windows 10 / Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600
・Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1

かなり古い CPU を利用しているようですが、仮想化テクノロジを有効化するには CPU と合わせて BIOS も対応している必要があります。
該当 CPU (Core i7-2600) のスペック を見る限り、VT-x 等には対応しているようですが、BIOS の設定メニューに項目が見つからないのであれば、そのマザーボードは対応していない事になります。
参考:
使用中のプロセッサーはインテル® バーチャライゼーション・テクノロジーに対応していますか?

Q: インテル® バーチャライゼーション・テクノロジー (VT-x) を有効または無効にするにはどうすれば良いですか？
VT-x をサポートするインテル® プロセッサーおよび VT-x をサポートする BIOS を使用することで、BIOS で VT-x を有効または無効にできます。BIOS にてオプションが利用できない場合の正確な手順についてはマザーボードのベンダーにお問い合わせださい。
Q: 私のプロセッサーはインテル® バーチャライゼーション・テクノロジー (VT-x) をサポートしていますが BIOS で有効にできません。
プロセッサーが VT-x をサポートしているが BIOS で有効または無効にするオプションが利用可能な場合、マザーボードのベンダーに連絡してそのオプションを有効にする方法をご確認ください。

